# how to print a document without having displayed the address at the bottom of the page in php or javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
              <script language="Javascript1.2">

                var message = "Print";
                function printpage() {
                window.print();

                }

                document.write("<center><input type=submit class=print id=non-printable value=print  onClick=\"printpage()\"/></center>");

            </script>
</body>
</html>
```

i want to generate bill but with this code but it displays address at the bottom of the page which will be printed, i dont want the address to be displayed at the bottom.
Please help with code in php or javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a browser setting and can't be altered using PHP/Javascript. Check your browsers printer settings to disable the header/footer text upon printing.

For creating reports I suggest you have a look at the [PHPExcel library](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/).

Comment: okay thanks. Do u know any other method in php to generate bill or reports

Comment: Added a library that I suggest for creating reports in my answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

considering google docs creates a pdf and then prints, i would suggest you do the same

Comment: OT: But I always thought google docs was a horrible printing method. Having to generate a pdf from a webpage then download it and open a pdf reader just to print what was on the webpage

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is somehow disabling the headers and footers that is added while printing.

This is actually a print option and can be disabled in print settings.

There is a workaround in CSS that you can use.
Note: Works only in Modern Browsers.

```
<head>
 <style type="text/css" media="print">
  @page 
  {
    size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
    margin: 0mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
  }

  body 
  {
    background-color:#FFFFFF; 
    border: solid 1px black ;
    margin: 0px;  /* this affects the margin on the content before sending to printer*/
  }
  </style>
  </head>
```

Comment: great, thank you. do you know any other method to generate php reports??

Comment: as @kennyDs pointed out, you can have a look at [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)